# NLog mySQL target configuration

Tags: mysql, target, nlog

I am trying out NLog to use mySQL table. I seem to have the configuration set correctly however I am getting the following error (capturing exceptions in NLog).

2012-10-10 17:09:20.0200 Error Error initializing target Database Target[slogger] System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.InitializeTarget()
   at NLog.Targets.Target.Initialize(LoggingConfiguration configuration).

I think that this error is related to the statement "The parameter name should be a provider invariant name as registered in machine.config or app.config" in the database target configuration page however I am not certain how to correct the error. I have the mySQL DLL referenced in the application.

Following is my configuration:

[image: nlog target]

Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly and how to change. I really appreciate help. This is really a cool app!

Thanks

Ray

Answer (score 1):

try changing the dbProvider to this

`dbProvider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data"`